# SQLAlchemy: Update values in table based on values update in other table

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have two tables with following fileds:

```
"category":
id: int - primary key
item_count: int
```

```
"subcategory":
id: int - primary key
parent_id: int - foreign key
item count: int
```

Tables are linked by `category.id = subcategory.parent_id`.

Is it possible to set this tables up so after every successful transaction column `category.item_count` would update based on sum of child subcategoruies item count?
Like automatically running something like

```
UPDATE category
SET item_count =
  (SELECT sum(item_count)
   FROM subcategory
   WHERE parent_id = category.id)
```

Example:
Initial `category` table state:
[image: initial category state:]

Then I add some rows to `sybcategory` table:
[image: add subcategory rows]

After that I want `category` table autoupdate and look like this:
[image: category afted update]

I'm using latest PostgresSQL and SQLAlchemy in Python.

I've tried to create `category.item_count` column as a generated postgres column like

```
ALTER TABLE category
ADD COLUMN item_count integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((SELECT COALESCE(SUM(item_count), 0) FROM subcategory WHERE parent_id = category.id)) STORED;
```

but got error message saying that I can't use subqueries in generated column expression.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a trigger:

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_category_count()
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS
'
BEGIN
UPDATE category SET item_count = (SELECT sum(item_count) FROM subcategory WHERE parent_id = category.id);
RETURN NEW;
END;
'
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER t_update_category_count AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON subcategory EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_category_count();
```

`update_category_count` is a function which returns a trigger which runs your update query. `CREATE TRIGGER` is then used to call the function after an insert or update occurs on `subcategory`.

Here's a [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i2X2SrYbjLJtgnF6jfpVJj/1) to demonstrate.